# Reduce time for Loop over multiple objects to get value Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Dataframe in which a column `Code` is increased significantly everyday and these codes are to be converted into object description for which I am doing something like the following:

```
    product = []
    beacon = []
    count = []
    c_start = time.time()
    for i, v in df["D Code"].iteritems():
        product.append(Product.objects.get(short_code=v[:2]).description)  #how to optimize this?
        beacon.append("RFID")
        count.append(v[-5:])
    c_end = time.time()
    print("D Code loop time ", c_end-c_start)
```

Now initially when the rows were less it used to work in no time but as the data increased the combined Database call for every code takes too much time. Is there any more efficient Django method to loop over a list and get the value?

The `df['D Code`]` looks something like this:

```
['TRRFF.1T22AD0029',
  'TRRFF.1T22AD0041',
  'TRRFF.1T22AD0009',
  'TRRFF.1T22AD0032',
  'TRRFF.1T22AD0028',
  'TRRFF.1T22AD0026',
  'TRRFF.1T22AD0040',
  'HTRFF.1T22AD0003',
  'TRRFF.1T22AD0048',
  'PPRFP.1T22AD0017',
  'TRRFF.1T22AD0047',
  'TRRFF.1T22AD0005',
  'TRRFF.1T22AD0033',
  'TRRFF.1T22AD0024',
  'TRRFF.1T22AD0042'],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a lookup dict with just one query. Then use that dict to find your description.

```
description_dict = {}
for product in Product.objects.values('short_code', 'description'):
    description_dict[product['short_code'] = product['description']

for i, v in df["D Code"].iteritems():
        product.append(description_dict[v[:2]])
        ...
```